# Input validation ( with multiple values )

Tags: c, validation, input

For school, I wrote a program to calculate the voltage and current of an bridge circuit with bridge resistance.

My problem is that I want the user to enter all resistances as a CSV (R1, R2, R3...). I want to validate the user input to check if only floats or integers are entered.

I wrote this do-while loop for the validation, to force the user to re-enter the values if the input isn't valid:

```
int check = 1;
do{
  if(check == 0){                                                           
    check = 1;
    puts("Re-Enter as the following: R1, R2, R3, R4, Rab");
  }//endif
  check = scanf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f", &fR1, &fR2, &fR3, &fR4, &fRab);           
  fflush(stdin);
}while(check == 0);
check = 1;
```

**EDIT**

This code just "throws" an "error" if the user enters letters or the wrong count of arguments (for example: 12, 12, [ENTER]). What is the best way to validate the user-input?

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: OP, did you even test this...like *once*?

Comment: Ok,for starters, what does `scanf` return?  What happens when the user enters "12.0. 12".  What's the value of check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get safe input is to use `fgets` and read the whole input as a string. You can then verify that the string is sane, and after that you can parse out the individual numbers (with for example `sscanf`).

`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, the function is only well-defined for output streams. Therefore this line cause your program to crash, burn or seemingly work as expected. Flush the line feed character away from stdin using `getchar()` instead, [read this](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html).